# jQuery mobile - force pagebeforeshow without knowing the page name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a small jQuery Mobile site with `NavBar` at the bottom of every page. The bar has some buttons, which should work across the site.

How to force `pagebeforeshow` event (on current viewed page) without knowing the page name/id?

Is there a general function to do this, or do I need to get `name/id` of the page first and them use this to call `pagebeforeshow`?

---

**UPDATE**

The following gets me a current page ID, but the `trigger("refresh")` does not seams to trigger any action (`pagebeforeshow` does not execute).

```
var CurrentPageID = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;
$("#" + CurrentPageID).trigger("refresh");
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Nn98Y/) a working example.

This will start page reload while clicking on navbar:

```
$('div[data-role="navbar"] ul li').bind('click',function(event, ui){
  $.mobile.changePage(
    '#'+$.mobile.activePage[0].id,
    {
      allowSamePageTransition : true,
      transition              : 'none',
      showLoadMsg             : false,
      reloadPage              : false
    }
  );
});
```

This code will catch pagebeforeshow:

```
$('#pageID').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){
    alert('Reload');
    //Execute AJAX here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume all the page you are navigating is divs with `data-role` attr. So you should able to bind event as below;

```
$('div[data-role="page"]').live( 'pagebeforeshow', showLoadDiv);

function showLoadDiv() {
   //Your code here
}

//when you want to call it manually
showLoadDiv();
```

Comment: I already have that event, what I am after is how to force the `pagebeforeshow` to execute from a button click event.

Comment: To execute pagebeforeshow you must activate a page transition to another page. So do you want to reload a current page or to switch to another one?

Comment: I have edited my answer, if you want to call the loading function (not event) you can use the above code bit.

Comment: I want to reload current page (refresh, get new data).

Comment: My `pagebeforeshow` has some AJAX which is loading data, after the click on NavBar, I want to run the AJAX (within pagebeforeshow) to get new data.